# I am trying to output the times in my code in hours and mins (00:00) and need help. This is what i have so far

Tags: java

I have my code, but in Solution 3 I am looking to convert the time in mins to hours and mins (i.e. 341 mins to 5 hours 41 mins).

```
  public class CityToSurf
  {
        //Method for lowest time index
        private int getMinIndex(int[] times){
        int minValue = times[0]; 
        int minIndex = 0;//default value to start with
        for(int counter=0;counter<times.length;counter++){  
            if(times[counter] < minValue){ 
              minIndex = counter;
              minValue = times[counter]; 
            }  
           }   
           return minIndex; 
        }
        public static void main (String[] arguments){

        CityToSurf cs = new CityToSurf();

        //create array of times and names
        int[] times ={341,273,278,329,445,402,388,275,243,334,412,393,299,343,317,265};
        String[] names ={"Elana","Thomas","Hamilton", "Suzie", "Phil","Matt", "Alex", "Emma", "John","James" ,"Jane", "Emily", "Daniel" ,"Neda", "Aaron", "Kate"};

        //Solution 1      
        int fastestRunnerIndex =  cs.getMinIndex(times);
        System.out.println("Solution 1:");
        System.out.println(names[fastestRunnerIndex]+ "  "+ times[fastestRunnerIndex] );

        //Solution 2
        System.out.println("Solution 2:");
        cs.getSortedArray(times, names);

      //Solution 3
        System.out.println("Solution 3:");
        cs.timeConvert(times, names);


    }

    private void getSortedArray(int[] times, String[] names){

         //store in a local variable the unchanged/old list
         int[] oldTimes = new  int[times.length];

         for (int i=0;i<times.length;i++){
              oldTimes[i] = times[i];

         }

         java.util.Arrays.sort(times);//sort the times from min to max times for the PLACEMENT

         int place =1; //this is to initialize the placement for a list from 1 to 16.

        //loop over my old times list and match the time in the old times with sorted times to find the corresponding index that will be used to get name and time
         for (int i=0;i<times.length;i++){
             //SORTED the min to max time from the list 
             int newSortedTime= times[i];


             //loop over the sorted times to match the time
             int oldIndex =0;
             for (int j=0; j<oldTimes.length;j++){
                 int oldUnsortedTime = oldTimes[j];

                 if (oldUnsortedTime == newSortedTime){
                     oldIndex = j;
                     System.out.println(place + "  " +names[oldIndex] + "   "  + oldTimes[oldIndex] );
                     place++;//increment to next placement
                 }

             }  }

         }

    private void timeConvert(int[] times, String[] names){
        int[] oldTimes = new  int[times.length];
        int hours = times / 60; //since both are ints, you get an int
        int minutes = times % 60;
        System.out.printf("%d:%02d", hours, minutes);
             }



    }
```

Comment: And the problem is...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

times is not an int it is int[] hence this will not work. I think you are looking something similar to:

```
  private void timeConvert(int[] times, String[] names) {
    for (int time : times) {
      int hours = time / 60; //since both are ints, you get an int
      int minutes = time % 60;
      System.out.printf("%d:%02d\n", hours, minutes);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this:

private void timeConvert(int[] times, String[] names){

```
int length = times.length ;
    for(int i = 0;i<length;i++){
         int hours = times[i] / 60;           
         int minutes = times[i] % 60;
         System.out.printf("%d:%02d", hours, minutes);
    }
}
```